# Pandas error tokenizing data when field in csv file contains quotation mark

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm using `pandas.read_csv` to read a tab delimited file and am running into the error: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 364 fields in line 73058, saw 398

After much searching, it seems that the offending entry is: `"– SO ,쳌  \\ ?Œ  ø ,d -L ,ú ,‚ ZO`

Removing the quotation mark seems to solve things. I've got a lot of large files with a lot of strange characters in them, so this will no doubt repeat itself. Do I need to remove single quotation marks ahead of time or is there some way around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a quoting argument for [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html):

```
quoting : int or csv.QUOTE_* instance, default None
    Control field quoting behavior per ``csv.QUOTE_*`` constants. Use one of
    QUOTE_MINIMAL (0), QUOTE_ALL (1), QUOTE_NONNUMERIC (2) or QUOTE_NONE (3).
    Default (None) results in QUOTE_MINIMAL behavior.
```

These are [described in the csv docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_ALL).

Try setting `quoting=3` (i.e. `QUOTE_NONE`).